# Magento 1.9 date picker with only month and year

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, calendar

At frontend i have to add Date-picker where have to show only Month and Year(not date) with year in range(like 1990 - 2020).

Please suggest me how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you this solution with Bootstrap Datepicker, Demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amir_prince/96kc4p7w/4/)

```
<!--Html part-->
    <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="" data-date-format="mm-yyyy"> 
        <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date" >     
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>   
    </div>

<!--Js part-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
    });
</script>
```

More informations in : [Bootstrap datepicker doc](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled)

Nb: don't forget to include this if you don't have theme:

- bootstrap-combined.min.css
- datepicker.css
- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: Prince i have one more problem, please can you look into this   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180915/add-two-delete-action-in-magneto-a-admin-controller-for-delete-form   Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, if it's ok, you can accept the answer

Comment: Prince please can you help me on  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180915/add-two-delete-action-in-magneto-a-admin-controller-for-delete-form

Comment: I'll take a look in a moment

Comment: @Prince How can i do, the customer chooses the date on PDP page. It is necessary field customer need to choose which date your products want to deliver. How can i add the calendar on PDP Page?